# How to make excel read only with the yellow bar to enable editing

Tags: excel-2010

Hello i'm looking into excel and i want to make the file read only when opend so the person who opens it can't make unwanted changes. but he needs to just simply press the enable editing button on the yellow bar.
[image of the yellow bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Oje.png) to be able to make changes.i do not wan't to work with a password. how do i make it that the yellow bar apears when i open the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like that:
go to info -> protect workbook->mark as final.
then no one will be able to edit the file.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this simple solution. i searched  so much but only ended up with password protecions and unchangable read-only files.